# Xdebug stops on xdebug_break() but not on breakpoints in PhpStorm during PHPUnit run

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I used to be able to stop on break points during my PHPUnit runs, but a recent PhpStorm update has messed that up.  I am able to use `xdebug_break()` but not an IDE break point.

Anyone else had that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by fixing my config.

1. Go to: Preferences->Languages & Frameworks->PHP->Servers
2. Make sure the 'Absolute path on server' correctly correlates to your project.

Mine was blank so I had to set it.